# Print database string when searched only part of it (via PHP statements)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a input type text and submit as search bar on my page. I want my php script to print all names from table that contain inserted string as part of itself. Currently this script only prints information if whole name is written within text input. But I also want it to show if only part of it is written within it.

```
private function search(){
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        # Database connection
          $db = $this->db;
          $db->set_charset('utf8');
        # check connection
          if (!$db) {
            echo "connection fail";
          }

        # HTML output (pt. 1)
        $output = '
          <table>
        ';

        # SQL query
        $q = '
        SELECT imeStud, prezStud
        FROM stud
        WHERE imeStud LIKE ?
        ';

        # process SQL query
        $search_input = $_POST['search'];
        if ($stmt = $db->prepare($q)) {
          $stmt->bind_param('s',$search_input);
          $stmt->bind_result($ime,$prezime);
          $stmt->execute();
          while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $output .= '
              <tr><td>'.$ime.'</td><td>'.$prezime.'</td></tr>
            ';
          }
        }

        # HTML output (pt. 3)
        $output .= '</table>';
        echo $output;
      }

  }#endfunc(search())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the most things, just add a wildcard before and after your search term

```
-        $search_input = $_POST['search'];
+        $search_input = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
```

or

```
-          $stmt->bind_param('s',$search_input);
+          $stmt->bind_result('s','%' . $search_input . '%');
```

Comment: I replaced these two and it returns me : Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in D:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\.....

Comment: @Kuno missed this, I usually use PDO. Since bind_param needs a reference we can't use a concat expression here. I've edited the answer above, either use bind_result (which expects a value) or add the wildcards earlier.